# resources not found - android

Tags: java, android, exception, resources

I have had my first errors come through via the developer console on a published app. The errors are:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fetchfree.diss.ellis/fetchfree.diss.ellis.Intro}: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030007
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030007
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
    at fetchfree.diss.ellis.Intro.onCreate(Intro.java:47)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    ... 11 more
```

The app is running fine on my devices (S2,S3,S4 and galaxy ace) and the emulator and ***have not been able to replicate this***. The resources its referring to at #0x7f030007 is a layout file for my setContentView of the Intro activity.

Resources:

```
Layout-normal-hdpi
Layout-normal-mdpi
Layout-sw360dp
```

My manifest states:

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:smallScreens="false" />
```

Comment: Can you post the layout code attached to Intro.java's on Create ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen generally because the version uploaded to the playstore would not match the release apk. Best way is to clean the project in eclipse, build, release and then upload the apk to the play store. If this still happens you can check for a few more things I've gathered while searching for a similar issue on SO

1.) Make sure that your imports are correct. R.java must be your local R.java and not Android.R . Do a check in all your files

2.) Make sure you are not passing integer values to Views. 
For instance dont do this

```
int i = 5;
myTextView.setText(i);
```

But do this

```
myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

I suspect this to be a problem with you , so scan your code for this type of errors.

The compiler will not complain.

3.) Use this way of declaration

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

rather than

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

for id declarations

Make these changes if any, clean, build and upload. Should work.